# {{#each}} and spinner DOM timing

Tags: meteor

I have list of ~150 entries with various filters/sorts.
By default when I have 10 shown response times are OK (it is not slow JS code, as the limiting to 10 is done as last step).
But when I hit expand button it takes 2s to show all entries.
And same time to apply filters/sort etc.

The helper used in {{#each}} is ReactiveVar which returns array.
I want to show spinner before re-rendering of #each starts and turn it off after it finishes.
Something like this pseudocode if it waits for every step to finish and also update DOM.

```
Tracker.autorun ->
  spinner.set(true)
  showFeed.set(resultFeed.get())
  spinner.set(false)
```

But if I dont use Meteor.setTimeout to defer that showFeed.set, the spinner is never shown. I dont want to rely on setTimeout. But I dont understand whole flush() afterFlush() enough to pull this off. How can I time it that it waits to finish every of these steps (also with DOM update) before proceeding to next ?

Comment: You can't write synchronous code on the client. There are no fibers on the client. You'll somehow need to find a callback function where you can place the `set(false)`. The better question might be why this is so slow (it shouldn't be).

Comment: there are few #if in every child template and some small computations using helpers. But still from Tracker documentation, I would expect that there is possibility how to force rendering of that Spinner before it jumps onto computing my filters and rendering that #each block.
I am experimenting now if I will be able to prepare data for child template to the state that there will be absolutely no logic in them, just simple showing of properties to speed it up. But still there is a delay when I ask for rendering even 200 static elements into DOM. And user have no feedback while it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to show spinner while DOM is updating, but I would like to suggest you another option: you can improve DOM updates performance by hiding/showing DOM nodes instead of creating/destroying them.

Let me show an example:

**Expensive DOM updates (create/destroy):**

HTML:

```
<template name="items">
  {{#each filteredItems as item}}
    <div class="item">
      {{item.content}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

COFFEE:

```
Template.helpers.items
  filteredItems: -> Session.get('filteredItems')

onFiltering ->
  Session.set('filteredItems', computeFilteredItems());
```

Why is this expensieve? Because everytime you do filtering, Blaze will create/destroy DOM nodes and this operation is rather expensieve.

**Cheap DOM updates (show/hide):**

HTML:

```
<template name="items">
  {{#each allItems as item}}
    <div class="item {{#if isItemVisible item}}item--visible{{/if}}">
      {{item.content}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

COFFEE:

```
Template.helpers.items
  allItems: -> allItems
  isItemVisible: -> Session.get('filteredItemsIds').indexOf(item._id) !== -1

onFiltering ->
  Session.set('filteredItemsIds', computeFilteredItems().map((item) -> item._id))
```

CSS:

```
.item {
  display: none;
}

.item--visible {
  display: block;
}
```

Why is it cheap? Because no DOM nodes will be created/destroyed dynamically, all required nodes will be created on the first rendering. We just add/remove CSS classes dynamically and this operation is way more cheaper than create/destroy.

---

P.S. I have not perfomed any tests, so I'm not 100% sure, but theretically it should work.